# problema de acentuação quando salva no banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Está acontecendo um problema comigo, quando eu salvo um valor no banco de dados, ele salva sem acentuação.

Todo o meu código na página está utf8, todo o meu banco de dados está utf8, as tabelas estão utf8 e onde faz o insert está utf8

Quando eu coloco utf8_encode() no código, ele funciona, porém quando resgato o valor, vem com o mesmo problema de acentuação

```
public function cadastrarResponsavel(){
        try{
            $sql = "INSERT INTO $this->prt_partner_responsible(id_resp,nome,cargo,tel_comercial1,tel_comercial2,tel_celular1,tel_celular2,email1,email2,nota,_id_partner,_ativo,_data_registro )
VALUES (NULL,:nome,:cargo,:tel_comercial1,:tel_comercial2,:tel_celular1,:tel_celular2,:email1,:email2,:nota,:id_partner,:ativo,:data_registro)";
            $stmt = DB::prepare($sql);


            foreach($this->nomeResponsavel as $key => $values) {

                $stmt->bindParam(":nome", $this->nomeResponsavel[$key], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(":cargo", $this->cargoResponsavel[$key], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(":tel_comercial1", $this->telefoneComercial1Resp[$key], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(":tel_comercial2", $this->telefoneComercial2Resp[$key], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(":tel_celular1", $this->telefoneCelularIIResp[$key], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(":tel_celular2", $this->telefoneCelularIIResp[$key], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(":email1", $this->email1Resp[$key], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(":email2", $this->emaiI2Resp[$key], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(":nota", $this->comentariosResp[$key], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(":id_partner", $this->idParceiro, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(":ativo", $this->ativo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(":data_registro", $this->datas, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->execute();
            }
            return $stmt->rowCount();
        }catch (PDOException $ex){
            $Exc = new ExceptionDatabase();
            date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
            $dataRegistro = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $this->Caminho = explode("/", $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
            $this->arquivo = $this->Caminho[count($this->Caminho)-1];
            $this->arquivoLog = 'log/erros.txt';
            $this->erro =  $ex->getCode();
            $this->mensagem  = $ex->getMessage();

            $Exc->setTipoLog(enum::Error);
            $Exc->setTitleLog($ex->errorInfo);
            $Exc->setDescLog($ex->getMessage());
            $Exc->setDataRegistro($dataRegistro);
            $Exc->setArquivo($this->arquivo);
            $Exc->setArquivoLog($this->arquivoLog);
            $Exc->setErro($this->erro);
            $Exc->setMensagem($this->mensagem);

            $Exc->erro();
        }
    }
```

[image: Está utf8]

Ele salva no banco assim

[image: Ele salva assim]

**Querys de conexão**

Basicamente tentei de duas formas

Setando o utf8 no config e chamando na class DB

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'); //ja tinha esse header utf8
define('DB_HOST', 'host qualquer' ); //host
define('DB_NAME', 'banco de dados qualquer'); //nome do servidor
define('DB_USER', 'usuario qualquer');  // nome do usuario
define('DB_PASS', 'senha qualquer');   //nome da senha
define('DB_CHARSET','charset=utf8"');  //codificação
```

e setar ele na classe de conexao

```
require_once 'config.php';
class DB{
    private static $instance;
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if(!isset(self::$instance))
        {
            try
            {
                self::$instance = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS,DB_CHARSET);
                //self::$instance->exec("set names utf8");
                self::$instance->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                self::$instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            } catch (PDOException $e)
            {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public static function prepare($sql){
        return self::getInstance()->prepare($sql);
    }
}
```

e também colocando o exec direto, não funcionou

```
require_once 'config.php';
class DB{
    private static $instance;
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if(!isset(self::$instance))
        {
            try
            {
                self::$instance = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
                self::$instance->exec("set names utf8");
                self::$instance->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                self::$instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

            } catch (PDOException $e)
            {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }


    public static function prepare($sql){
        return self::getInstance()->prepare($sql);
    }
}
```

**nem executa**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

executa normalmente, mas bagunça toda a codificação
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Defina na conexão do PDO o charset utf8.

Sua string de conexão ficaria parecido com isto:

```
"mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=utf8"
```

Se estiver utilizando uma versão do PHP antiga, esse comando é ignorado, aí você deve setar via comando, como este:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:$connstr",  $user, $password);
$dbh->exec("set names utf8");
```

Tente realizar essa configuração e veja se resolve.

Comment: blz, vou tentar

Comment: não funcionou, nem executa a conexão

Comment: Após sua alteração, como ficou sua string de conexão? pode me mandar para verificar?

Comment: vou editar minha questão.

Comment: Olha ai @Bruno Rigolon, editei

Comment: Vamos lá, tente colocar essa linha no lugar da sua:

self::$instance = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME . ';charset=utf8', DB_USER, DB_PASS, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'") );

Comment: ele nem conecta ao banco

Comment: na verdade conecta, mas bagunça a codificação

Comment: Perfeito, deixe assim, agora veja sua página se está em UTF-8. O @Sorack mencionou um post, acredito estar relacionado também. Tem que verificar a página (charset definido no arquivo), conexão com o banco e charsets definidos.

Comment: cara, tudo está em utf8, já conferi tudo]

Comment: Se nada funcionou, sugiro a tentar isolar o problema. Crie um arquivo PHP separado de tudo, coloque o código da sua classe, faça a conexão e liste os dados e veja se vai ocorrer o problema. Neste arquivo simule a inserção dos dados do UTF8 e sem e veja o que vai ocorrer. De acordo com estes dados você vai ter uma ideia melhor do que está ocorrendo.

Comment: o que tu diz, fazer um db, uma tabela, conexão, tudo de teste?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59686/discussion-between-bruno-rigolon-and-gabrielfalieri).

Answer (score 0):

Problema solucionado, o erro estava quando eu tentava enviar os dados com o utf8_encode, visto que eu tinha passado tudo pra utf8